# Why does .NET List Sort() not take an explicitly declared delegate object?

Tags: c#, sorting, generics, delegates

Quick question.

In the second example on [this documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the second code block, featuring a method called CompareDinosByLength), the Sort method is called as such:

```
dinosaurs.Sort(CompareDinosByLength);
```

Why is it that the Sort method didn't need an explicitly declared delegate, as I would have thought by reading the Delegate documentation? Before I found that example, I was attempting to do it like so:

```
delegate int CompareDinosDel(string first, string second);
CompareDinosDel newDel = CompareDinosByLength;
dinosaurs.Sort(newDel);
```

But I kept getting errors related to the delegate / delegate method not being proper Comparers.

Shouldn't both work?

Comment: what type of `dinosaurs` list elements?

Comment: It might be because OrderBy which basically does the same thing does take a delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dinosaurs.Sort(CompareDinosByLength);

CompareDinosDel newDel = CompareDinosByLength;
dinosaurs.Sort(newDel);
```

> Shouldn't both work?

No, because you are passing two very different things into those two function calls.

The key here is to recognize that, in both cases, what you actually pass into the method *is* a delegate. In the first case, the compiler is implicitly creating a delegate of the correct type for you, even though you didn't explicitly ask it to. In the second case, you're making your own delegate, but it's the wrong type, so that attempt will fail.

Starting with .NET 2.0, the C# compiler allow you to skip explicitly create delegates in many situations. If you use a method name in a context where a delegate is expected, and the compiler can verify that the method signature and delegate signature match, it will implicitly construct a delegate instance using the method. That is, instead of doing this (the "old" way)

```
this.SubmitButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SubmitButton_Click);
```

You can now do this:

```
this.SubmitButton.Click += this.SubmitButton_Click;
```

Visual Studio itself will still generate the older syntax, I assume because it still works and because it's not worth the developer's time to go messing around with it for very little benefit. However, most popular code analysis tools will flag the redundant delegate creation if you use it in your own code.

This same technique works anywhere you have a method (technically a "method group", since one method name can refer to more than one overload), and you assign it to a variable of a delegate type. Passing a method as a parameter into another method is the same type of assignment operation: you are "assigning" the actual parameter at the call site to the formal parameter in the method body, so the compiler does the same thing. In other words, the following two method calls do exactly the same thing:

```
dinosaurs.Sort(CompareDinosByLength);
dinosaurs.Sort(new Comparison<string>(CompareDinosByLength));
```

Your unsuccessful attempt to make a delegate, on the other hand, did something slightly different:

```
dinosaurs.Sort(new CompareDinosDel(CompareDinosByLength));
```

This time, you told the compiler exactly what kind of delegate you wanted, but that's *not* the kind of delegate that the method expected. In general, the compiler isn't going to try to second guess what you told it do to; if you ask it to do something that looks "fishy", it will produce an error (in this case, a type mismatch error).

This behavior is similar to what would happen if you tried to do this:

```
public class A
{ 
   public int x;
}

public class B
{ 
   public int x;
}

public void Foo(A a) { }

public void Bar()
{
    B b = new B();
    this.Foo(b);
}
```

In this case, `A` and `B` are two distinct types, even though their "type signature" is exactly the same. Any line of code that works on an `A` will also work equally well on a `B`, but yet, we cannot use them interchangeably. Delegates are types like any other types, and C#'s type safety rules require that we use the *correct* delegate types where we need them, and can't get away with just using a *close enough* type.

The reason this is a good thing is because a delegate type may have a lot more meaning that just it's technical components would imply. Like any other data type, when we create delegates for our applications, we usually apply some kind of semantic meaning to those types. We expect, for example, that if we have a `ThreadStart` delegate, that it's going to be associated with a method that runs when a new thread starts. the delegate's signature is about as simple as you get (no parameters, no return value) but the implication behind the delegate is very important.

Because of that, we generally *want* the compiler to tell us if we try to use the wrong delegate type in the wrong place. More often than not, that's probably a sign that we are about to do something that may compile, and even run, but is likely to do *the wrong thing*. That's never something you want from your program.

---

While all that is true, it's also true that often times you really don't want to assign any semantic meaning to your delegates, or else, the meaning is assigned by some other part of your application. Sometimes you really do just want to pass around an arbitrary piece of code that has to run later. This is very common with functional-style programs or asynchronous programs, where you get things like continuations, callbacks, or user-supplied predicates (look at the various LINQ methods, for example).  .NET 3.5 and onward supply a very useful set of completely generic delegates, in the `Action` and `Func` family, for this purpose.

Comment: Easy to understand explanation! Thanks. So just to be clear, the delegate type that it wanted was a Comparison<T>; whereas I defined my own delegate type and tried to shove it in Sort? I think I assumed delegate types didn't matter as long as it represented the method that I wanted.

Comment: that's correct; delegate types work like any other type: just because two different delegate types 'look' the same does not make them assignment-compatible.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is it that the `Sort` method didn't need an explicitly declared delegate?

C# permits a *method group* -- that is, a method which is named without having the `(...)` argument list to invoke it -- to be used in a context where a delegate is expected. The compiler performs *overload resolution* on the method group *as though the method group had been invoked with arguments of the types of the delegate's formal parameters*. This determines which *method* of the *method group* should be used to create the delegate.

This overload resolution process can sometimes lead to unusual situations involving method type inference when the method group is undergoing overload resolution to a delegate type which is a formal parameter type of a generic method; `Sort`, fortunately is not a generic method, so these oddities do not come into play.

This feature was added to C# 2.0; before that a method group had to be converted to a delegate via

```
new MyDelegate(MyMethod)
```

> I keep getting errors related to the delegate / delegate method not being proper `Comparer`s. Shouldn't both work?

Unfortunately, no.  C# does not have *structural identity* on delegate types. That is:

```
delegate void Foo();
delegate void Bar();
...
Foo foo = ()=>{};
Bar bar = foo; // ERROR!
```

Even though `Foo` and `Bar` are *structurally* identical, the compiler disallows the conversion. You can however use the previous trick:

```
Bar bar = foo.Invoke;
```

This is equivalent to

```
Bar bar = new Bar(foo.Invoke);
```

However the new `bar` has as its action to invoke `foo`; it goes through a level of indirection.

This feature does make some sense.

Reason one:

You don't expect structural identity to work in other places:

```
struct Point { int x; int y; ... }
struct Pair { int key; int value; ... }
....
Point point = whatever;
Pair pair = point; // ERROR
```

Reason two:

You might want to say:

```
delegate int PureMethod(int);
```

And have a convention that `PureMethod` delegates are "pure" -- that is, the methods they represent do not throw, always return, return a value computed only from their argument, and produce no side effects. It should be an error to say

```
Func<int, int> f = x => { Console.WriteLine(x); return x+1; };
PureMethod p = f;
```

Because `f` is not pure.

However in hindsight people do not actually make semantics-laden delegates. It is a pain point that a value of type `Predicate<int>` cannot be assigned to a variable of type `Func<int, bool>` and vice versa.

If we had to do it all over again, I suspect that delegates would have structural identity in the CLR.

Finally, I note that VB is much more forgiving about inter-assigning mixed delegate types; it automatically builds an adapter delegate if it needs to.  This can be confusing because sometimes it looks like referential identity is maintained when in fact it is not, but this is in keeping with the VB philosophy of "just make my code work".

Comment: bleh. 2/3 of the way through typing my answer when this pops up. You type too fast.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I hope you post it anyways; you probably have some additional interesting insights.

Comment: These issues are mitigated by the (.Net 3.5+) `Func` and `Action` delegates.  If everyone agrees to use the same, standard delegates (except where semantics-laden delegates are explicitly needed), the need for structural identity goes away.  Sadly, the existence of `Predicate` makes the obvious choice a bit less obvious (Raymond Chen mentioned that MS has a time machine for these sort of problems).

Comment: @Brian: Good point. The addition in C# 4 of allowing covariant and contravariant conversions on these delegates is also helpful in many scenarios. (Though unfortunately delegate *addition* is somewhat messed up in a world with variant delegates; there were some bugs in there in the .NET 4 release that I'm not sure were ever fixed. I should look into that.)

Comment: @EricLippert thankfully, my answer was still sitting in the edit box when i came back so I didn't have to type it all up again...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: I have noticed that StackExchange is *extremely* good about retaining state even when the web browser client is behaving badly. This can be a tricky problem to solve and the development team has clearly put a lot of thought into it.

Comment: Thanks for the level of detail! I had to go look up several things in your explanation (=> operator, Invoke(), Predicate, Func, etc), but all good learning.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherFoo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Should I be able to say:

```
Foo foo = new SomeOtherFoo();
```

That won't work in C# either.  When you have two different types that have the same body/implementation, **they are still different types**.  Two classes with the same properties are still different classes.  Two different delegates with the same signature are still different delegates.

The `Sort` method has *already* defined the delegate type, and you need to match it.  This is very much like it defining a class that it needs to accept as a parameter; you can't just pass in another type with the same properties and methods.

This is what it means for a language to be statically typed.  An alternate type system would be to use "Duck Typing" in which the language doesn't apply the constraint that a variable be of a specific type, but rather that it has a specific set of members.  In other words, "If it walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, pretend it's a duck."  That is opposed to the style of typing that says, "It must be a duck, period, even if it knows how to walk and quack."

Comment: I remember reading one of Eric Lippert's comments where he says that just because two delegates have the same signature, that doesn't mean that there should be a hierarchical relation between the two. Which supports your assertion. If they had to take that decision today, he said, they *maaay* have chosen differently. (I can't seem to find the link though).

Comment: @dcastro It's worth noting that the decision was made before Eric joined the C# team.  He never made it to begin with.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed he also answered this question and said it again, no need to find the link :P (yeah, I edited my comment and changed it to "they" - as in, the team - instead of "he").